# Processing monad value before assignment

Tags: haskell, syntax

Is it possible to make those two lines one line:

```
main = do line <- getLine 
    let result = words line
```

what I mean is something like non monadic code

result = words getLine

which -- in my opinion -- would improve readability.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this: `result <- fmap words getLine`

`fmap` takes a function with a type like `a -> b` and turns it into `f a -> f b` for anything that's an instance of `Functor`, which *should* include all `Monad` instances.

There's an equivalent function called `liftM` that's specific to `Monad`, for murky historical reasons. You might need to use that instead in some cases, but for standard monads like `IO` you can stick with `fmap`.

You can also import `Data.Functor` or `Control.Applicative` to get a nice operator version of `fmap`, so you could write `words <$> getLine` instead, which often looks prettier.

Comment: I'm not positive this helps readability, though; I think your original might sometimes be better.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: If an intermediate value like `line` here is only used once in a simple expression, it's often more readable to do things this way. Naming a value means it could be used anywhere in that scope, which creates one more thing to keep track of when reading the whole definition.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: For readability I tend to prefer `<$>` over `fmap`, since it looks similar to `$`.

Comment: Agreed, but I'm not convinced that you should use either of them -- sometimes just doing the let-syntax from the OP is the best way.  (Sorry if that wasn't clear.)

Comment: (That was to @hammar; @CA: I agree in most cases, but just having a _name_ for values can sometimes be critical to readability.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman: I agree, but sometimes there isn't a good name for an intermediate value, and in those cases I'd rather have no name than a meaningless one.

Comment: Agreed, but it needed to be said that sometimes giving it a name is the right call.

Comment: There there, `(\line -> words line) <$> getLine` both preserves the name and does not pollute the scope.

Comment: "should include all Monad instances" -- yeah, I completely agree, but sadly, the instance-overriding mechanism in Haskell favors strictness over expressiveness. Hence, there isn't a default which makes all monads into functors, and `liftM` is therefore not useless.

Comment: @gatoatigrado http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal